What electoral factors facilitated the 2022 teal wave in Australia?
In the 2022 Australian Federal House of Representatives election, 5% of seats were won by "Teal independents" who ousted members of the former governing party. This seems surprising in the context of a stable two party system (as usually occurs if elections have few seats per electorate); for comparison, Australia's conventional 3rd party (the Greens) received 12% of first preferences but only 3% of seats.
What factors made those particular seats especially ripe for challengers from outside of the two major parties? Was there some consistent anomaly compared to other electorates (such as in campaign spending, or in degree of policy misalignment between the electorate and the major party platforms, or in the individual performance stats of the incumbents)?

You should do some research; read coverage of the election e.g. in ABC Australia, The Guardian, or other relevant media.

@StuartF I have done, can you be more specific?

I want to address one of your assumptions before I get stuck into the main points.

This seems surprising in the context of a stable two party system

I would challenge the idea that Australia has a stable two party system.  There are two dominant parties, that is true, but the vote shares of Labor and their main rival the Liberal National Party (LNP) have been falling beneath their feet for a few elections now.

The LNP's 1st preference vote share peaked in 2013 and dropped to 35.7% in 2022.  Labor is more stable, with a peak in 2016 (an election they lost), but they dropped vote share consistently since then, even in 2022 when they won.
The floor falling out of the LNP's 1st preference vote share is the short answer to your question - this is how the Teals won in their seats.
What made the now Teal seats ripe for challengers?
The Teal seats demographically span some of the wealthiest and educated parts of Australia.  Notably, out of the 7 seats won at the 2022 Federal Election, 5 of them are seats which are geographically located on the coast.  While the coastal living is an indicator of wealth, it also brings the issue of man made climate change to the forefront of many of these voters' mind. Big issues in these electorates are rising sea levels and coastal erosion.
The previous coalition government, led by Scott Morrison and Barnaby Joyce held a slim majority, and were very unpopular.  Both are climate skeptics, and had ushered the LNP into the modern conservative era, where the focus is on social and cultural issues.
Economic liberalism, what the LNP traditionally stood for, began to slip away.  Morrison's economic response to Covid, while initially praised, quickly fell out of favour with voters in these sorts of seats.  Australia, like many other western democracies, started to face rapid inflation towards the end of 2021.  This blame was left at Morrison's feet, and when paired with the climate skepticism, made the LNP a very unappealing choice for voters in these areas.
Another issue long plaguing the LNP was the issue of women.  While women aren't an issue for many political parties, the 2021 rape of Brittany Higgins in the parliamentary office of LNP Senator Linda Reynolds had a major effect for the LNP.  Scott Morrison and other members of the LNP were roundly criticized for their behaviour towards Miss Higgins, and to another survivor of child sexual abuse, 2021 Australian of the Year, Grace Tame.
What made the Teal independents such formidable opponents?
The Teal independents were certainly in the right seats, and they were there at the right time.  Climate 200, led by Simon Holmes à Court, played a critical role in recruiting the right independent women candidates, who were professionals with long careers outside of politics.  They were pitched as outsiders who could fix the issues that career politicians ignored and benefited from.
Climate 200 made sure the candidates provided staff to help the candidates set up their own teams, provided funding for advertisements and a set of political consultants they could work with to organise a professional campaign.  Politically, the Teal independents positioned themselves as progressive on social issues, economically liberal and focused on climate change.  It is very hard to imagine a more fitting political platform for running a campaign in the seats the Teal independents ended up winning.

You could get a better time-series (of first preference votes) using the table on p121 of Federal Election Results - Reissue #2 1901-2016.

It's universally considered a two-party system as the government has alternated exclusively between two parties, Labor and the (Liberal/National) Coalition, for over a century (and almost always in the form of a majority government). Because of ranked choice voting, diluting of first-preferences doesn't necessarily undermine two-party stability.

Yeah, I'm not suggesting that the Teal independents will form a governmental majority, nor am I suggesting that the LNP/Labor days of forming government are over.  My point is that you can't have the Teals wiping out so many seats in LNP-strongholds without the underlying decay of the LNP's 1st preference vote share.  I'm curious as to why you asked the question though, it seems like you have a strong grasp on the fundamentals.
